# Как использовать жесткий диск и в линуксе и в виндовс

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux, dual-boot, fdisk

На компьютере есть, один жесткий диск и две системы Kali Linux и windows как использовать диск D в обоих системах.

Comment: отформатировать диск так, что бы он понимался всеми системами - fat/ntfs и подмонтировать.

Comment: Грузить Kali только с флешки (как советуют на оффсайте), запускать GNU/Linux в VM (виртуальная машина - VirtualBox как пример)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Установить драйвер виндовозных разделов *ntfs-3g*
2. В каталоге /mnt/ создать подкаталоги *disk_c* и *disk_d*
3. Дописать в файл /etc/fstab нечто вроде:

   /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk_c ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
   /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk_d ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0

Какие именно устройства и куда монтировать - зависит от Вашей конфигурации.
Посмотрите, что выдаёт команда

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

и сориетируйтесь соответствующим образом